# What is the easiest way to get the latest comment on any of my videos, using v2 of the YouTube API?

Tags: youtube-api

As pointed out in the question [How do I fetch comments in version 3 of the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489329/how-do-i-fetch-comments-in-version-3-of-the-youtube-api), there is currently no way of fetching video comments using version 3 of the YouTube API. Now I'm trying to figure it out using version 2 instead.

What I want is the latest comment on any of my uploaded videos, in other words the latest comment in the "aggregated" comment feed of all my videos.

It seems like the only way to do this is too fetch all videos, and then make a call for each of them to get the comments. With a few hundred uploaded videos, this becomes very expensive in terms of number of API calls and total time for completion.

Is there a simpler and/or better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to be "notified" via the API when a video gets a new comment, so you're going to have to do some polling. The comments feed for a given video id, e.g. https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/fhWaJi1Hsfo/comments?v=2 for video id `fhWaJi1Hsfo`, is sorted in reverse-chronological order by default, so the last comment added should always be first in the list of entries.

Making a request for the comments feed of several hundred videos, even if you do that a couple of times a day, doesn't sound like an unreasonable amount of traffic. You should follow the best practices outlined in [this blog post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html) if you do run into any quota issues, though.