# Rate (like/dislike) YouTube comments

Tags: javascript, youtube, gdata

Simple problem:

I'm using Youtube gdata through javascript to: Comment, Reply and Like/Dislike videos. 
Everything is working so far!

However, I'm trying to allow users to specifically like and dislike COMMENTS (the same way you can on native youtube.com). But I can't actually find the docs that explain how this is done.

I tried sending the follow to `...://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[video_id]/ratings`

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
       xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <link rel="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#in-reply-to" 
          type="application/atom+xml" href="<ID>"/>
    <yt:rating value="like"/>
</entry>
```

But no joy. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You got video comments so I guess you use the V2 YouTube API, because [it's not possible in the V3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652190/1515819). And the V2 doc says:

> Each entry in the comments feed contains information about a single
>   comment. Each comment has an author, a title, content, and an
>   in-reply-to link.
>
> Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference?hl=fr&csw=1#Comments_Feeds

They don't speak about like nor dislikes. It is even not possible to GET the likes and dislikes amount for comments, so neither is it to SET them.