# Is there a way to add comments through YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api

Couldn't find it anywhere in the docs.

Is there a way to add a comment to a video with YouTube API v3?

Comment: i just browsed through the docs my self, your right i don't see any feature discussing about chat, votes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fetch comments in version 3 of the YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489329/how-do-i-fetch-comments-in-version-3-of-the-youtube-api)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for comments in v3 of the Youtube API. If you wanna work with comments you need to use v2 of the API. 
Here is a guide on how to use comments with the V2 API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments

Comment: never used the youtube api before, but why the heck would they remove that functionality?

Comment: @ddavison maybe they want to avoid spammers

Answer (score 4):

To create a top-level comment, use the `commentThreads.insert` method.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert

Answer (score 1):

According to the Youtube API blog, comments are only available on v2 at the moment, until a "modern" alternative comes along for v3: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2014/03/committing-to-youtube-data-api-v3.html