# How to retrieve comments and likes of YouTube Videos?

Tags: youtube-api

I want to retrieve comments and likes of YouTube videos.How can I do so?

I have searched for YouTube API can anyone tell me what is it and how to use it for retrieving comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fetch comments in version 3 of the YouTube API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489329/how-do-i-fetch-comments-in-version-3-of-the-youtube-api)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use v3 of the YouTube API to get comments, so you'll have to use v2.  That said, there are some upcoming changes to the way comments work since switching comments to Google+ in November 2013.  You can read about those changes here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/changes_to_comments

You can use the Video List endpoint to get the number of likes here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Jeff Posnick answered the comment part of the question here:
[How do I fetch comments in version 3 of the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13489329/how-do-i-fetch-comments-in-version-3-of-the-youtube-api)